# Dynamically declare child UiViewController in main UiViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

In my program, I have to declare and use the multiple child `UIViewController` like a custom control in my main `UIViewController`. But when I click on the button of one of the child UIView Controllers I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. Please see the following my sample code structure.

Example 1:

```
//--Child-------------------------------------------------------------------
@interface subUIViewController<UIViewController>

     -(IBAction)myButtonClick:(id)Sender;

-@implementation subUiViewController

     -(IBAction)myButtonClick:(id)Sender
     {
          NSLog(@"Button Click Event.....");
     }

//---Main--------------------------------------------------------------------

@interface mainUIViewController<UIViewController>

@implementation mainUIViewController

     -(void)viewDidLoad
     {
          [super viewDidLoad];
          subUiViewController *subViewController=[[subUiViewController alloc] initWithNibNameAndArtist:@"subUiViewController" bundle:nil];
          [self.view addSubView: subViewController.view];
     }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But if I declare with `@property (retain,nonatomic) subUiViewController *subViewController` in `MainViewController`, it is working without error. Please see the following code.

Example 2:

```
//---Child------------------------------------------------------------------
@interface subUIViewController<UIViewController>

     -(IBAction)myButtonClick:(id)Sender;

@implementation subUiViewController

     -(IBAction)myButtonClick:(id)Sender
     {
          NSLog(@"Button Click Event.....");
     }

//----Main-----------------------------------------------------------------


@interface mainUIViewController<UIViewController>
     @property(retain,nonatomic) subUiViewController *subViewController;

@implementation mainUIViewController
     @synthesize subViewController;

     -(void)viewDidLoad
     {
          [super viewDidLoad];
          subViewController=[[subUiViewController alloc] initWithNibNameAndArtist:@"subUiViewController" bundle:nil];
          [self.view addSubView: subViewController.view];
     }


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I don't know why Example 1 is not working and Example 2 is working. For me, I need to use example 1 because I need to programatically create a child ui view controller based on Core Data Return. Could you please help me to point out what is wrong ? How can I dynamically declare child ui view controller in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I can solve my problem after seeing the EricLars0n and user523234's suggestion. I appreciate it. Here is the way.

```
@interface mainUIViewController<UIViewController>
     @property(retain,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myViewControllers;

@implementation mainUIViewController
     @synthesize myViewControllers;

     -(void)viewDidLoad
     {
          [super viewDidLoad];

          //Sub View Controller 1
          subUiViewController *subViewController1=[[subUiViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"subUiViewController" bundle:nil];
          [self.myViewControllers addObject:subViewController1];
          [self.view addSubView: subViewController1.view];

          //Sub View Controller 2
          subUiViewController *subViewController2=[[subUiViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"subUiViewController" bundle:nil];
          [self.myViewControllers addObject:subViewController2];
          [self.view addSubView: subViewController2.view];
     }
```

I use the one **property type NSMutableArray** and store my programmatically created child UIViewControllers into this NSMutableArray. So, my child UiViewControllers no way to cease until viewDidUnload.

Thank Guys!

Answer (score 1):

In example 1

```
subUiViewController *subViewController
```

ceases to exist after viewDidLoad finishes. Normally in an iPhone app each screen is it's own view controller. And if you want to load a new screen/viewController you would create it like you did and either display it Modally or if you are using a navigationController push it on the stack.

But if you want to do what you are doing your main viewController would need a property of type id that could hold whatever type of viewController you create.

Depending on what you are doing the new ability in iOS 5 for a View Controller to be a container view controller for other view controllers might be useful. Specifically the method

```
addChildViewController:
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as EricLarSOn explained.  However, in your situation, what you can do it to declare  generic var with property and instaintiate whatever the childviewcontroller class dynamically and assigned it to the generic var as mentioned earlier.
For example replace your

@property(retain,nonatomic) subUiViewController *subViewController;

With:

@property(retain,nonatomic) UIViewController *myUIViewController;

And then

subUiViewController *subViewController=[[subUiViewController alloc] initWithNibNameAndArtist:@"subUiViewController" bundle:nil];

Add this line

self.myUIViewController = subViewController;

[subViewController release];

[self.view addSubView: self.myUIViewController.view];

Comment: Thanks guy, but it still give me same error. My application use ARC.

Comment: If you use ARC, remove this line
[subViewController release];